# Angularjs ng-show with expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to use ng-show with an expression?

I am trying to filter a ng-repeat with the result of a checkbox click. I can view the expression but not in a ng-show or ng-init.

The value displays in the ng-init but not as a string.

This is my input

```
<input ng-model="search.result" value="{{car.vehicleKey}}" type="radio" id="{{car.vehicleKey}}">
```

And this is my filtering

```
<div ng-init="outerIndex = {{search.result}}">
search.result = {{search.result}} and outerIndex = {{outerIndex}}

 <div ng-repeat="car in cars" ng-show="car.vehicleKey == outerIndex">
```

Comment: you can use ng-show="car.vehicleKey == search.result" , is there any problem with your use case ?

Comment: I think there's an extra space after 'car' in your ng-show